# Not-Zend-style URLs and routing

Tags: zend-framework

I am rewriting a website from a homemade engine to Zend Framework. On this site most pages' urls used to end with `.html` by design, even though they were php scripts. Say, all of them look like `/category/page.html` or `/category.html`. I have to use the same naming scheme in the new Zend version of the site. So I need pages with urls like `^(.*)\.html$` (lets call them page A) to render the page that would be rendered if it was the same url, but without `.html` (page B). So pages

```
/news/superman-was-caught-naked.html
```

and

```
/news/superman-was-caught-naked
```

should render the same content. How to make old .html-y page A use page B's controller and action?

Comment: What you need are [routes](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.router.html).

Comment: And maybe [rewrite rules](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/)

Comment: And just as a friendly note, those URLs should either a) not render the same content - and use a redirect from one to the other - or b) use a canonical rel tag so that search engines don't get confused.